# Property 'scr' does not exist on type 'Element' in mediaStream and Angular 4

Tags: angular, webrtc, mediastream

I am using `getUserMedia` to displaying the live stream from the webcam.

My `app.component.html` is

```
// to show webcam video
<video id="vid1" autoplay></video>

// to show recieved stream from other user.
<video id="vid2" autoplay></video>
```

and `app.component.ts`

```
navigatorr.getUserMedia(constraints, function (stream) {
    const video = document.querySelector('#vid1');

    // inserting our stream to the video tag
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);

 }
```

It is giving an error that

> Property 'src' does not exist on type 'Element'.

But If I am using

```
const video = document.querySelector('video');
```

It is working, But then How will I show the video of the received stream.

How to solve this problem, Please someone help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast Element to HTMLVideoElement: 
Try this:

```
navigatorr.getUserMedia(constraints, function (stream) {
    const video = <HTMLVideoElement>(document.querySelector('#vid1'));

    // inserting our stream to the video tag
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);

 }
```

Comment: It's working. Can I do the same to show the received media stream?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
document.getElementById("vid1").src= window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
```

Comment: New error `Property 'src' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.`

Comment: are you displaying live stream?

Comment: Yes. I am displaying the live stream getting from webcam.

Comment: URL.createObjectURL is no longer supported for MediaStreams as of Chrome 72.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the following variant works:

```
navigator.getUserMedia(constraints, function (stream) {
    const video: HTMLVideoElement = document.querySelector('#vid1');

    // inserting our stream to the video tag
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);

 }
```

P.S. `navigatorr` !== `navigator`